# C# Get a selected TabControl tab in Visual Studio WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I'm looking for the method which returns a bool on whether or not a tab in a `TabControl` is selected. I would think there would be something like `tabPage1.IsSelected()` but there isn't. I found this: [`TabControl.SelectedTab Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab(v=vs.110).aspx) However, this `SelectedTab` property is absent from my WinForms class for some reason. Not sure if it's been taken out or what. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code snippet, where you try to call SelectedTab

Comment: What would 'Selected' even mean in the context of a Tab Control?? If it has any pages then one __must__ be selected/visible.

Comment: bool happy = tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1;

Comment: Insert class that you want get selected tab with namespaces

Comment: [`SelectedTab`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab(v=vs.110).aspx) is a property of `TabControl` not the `TabPage`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code to know which tab is selected.

```
  private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {        
     if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabControl1.TabPages["operationstabPage"])
     {
           //add your code here
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected tab in tab control, you can use -

```
var selectedTab = this.tabControl1.SelectedTab;
```

So you can do -

```
bool tabSelected = this.tabControl1.SelectedTab == this.tabPage1;
```